# What does irb --simple-prompt do?

Tags: ruby, irb

What does irb --simple-prompt do? I'm using a tutorial that does not explain what the term does. I've looked at various websites for documentation but the only definition it gives is circular (--simple-prompt = simple prompt mode).

Comment: try it with and without:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It gives you a simpler prompt (lol). No ruby version and no line number.

Example using `irb --simple-prompt`:

```
user: $ irb --simple-prompt
>>
```

Example using `irb`:

```
user: $ irb
2.0.0-p353 :001 >
```

Comment: I get the line number, but what do you mean by ruby version?

Comment: I don't know on Windows but on my macbook I see something like
`2.3.1 :001 >`

Comment: Alright... I suppose the answer is good enough, and the version number explanation is trivial enough for it not to matter. One last thing, is there any advantage in removing the line numbers?

Comment: Sincerely I can't imagine a use case to strictly use a simple prompt. Personally I never used it.